# How to make images show in browsers

Tags: html, css

Just learning to code. And would like to know why my images aren't showing on my browser(s). Both Firefox and safari. I'm using an iMac computer (which is not a problem anyway).

Here is an example of the code:

```
<img src="images/fish08.jpg" alt="Big Fish" width="250" height="200">
```

Comment: Did you check your browser's console for errors?

Comment: This will most likely be a problem with the `src='path'` and the location of your file in your file structure

Answer (score 0):

Something must be wrong with your **source path**. Your code should work if this is your folder structure:

```
- fileWithImageElement.html
- images
    - fish08.jpg
```

Please read [HTML file paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) to see which one you should use.

Comment: All my images are in the images folder which is in the root folder.

Comment: `<img src="/images/picture.jpg">` This should work if your images folder is in the root folder according to HTML doc.